# mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-annotations

I am having an issue in setting up a one to many relationship in my annotated object.

I have the following:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class MappedModel
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id",nullable=false,unique=true)
    private Long mId;
```

then this

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer extends MappedModel implements Serializable
{

    /**
   * 
   */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -2543425088717298236L;


  /** The collection of stores. */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Collection<Store> stores;
```

and this

```
@Entity
@Table(name="store")
public class Store extends MappedModel implements Serializable
{

    /**
   * 
   */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -9017650847571487336L;

  /** many stores have a single customer **/
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn (name="customer_id",referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false,unique=true)
  private Customer mCustomer;
```

what am i doing incorrect here

Answer (score 203, accepted):

The `mappedBy` attribute is referencing `customer` while the property is `mCustomer`, hence the error message. So either change your mapping into:

```
/** The collection of stores. */
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "mCustomer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Collection<Store> stores;
```

Or change the entity property into `customer` (which is what I would do).

The mappedBy reference indicates "Go look over on the bean property named 'customer' on the thing I have a collection of to find the configuration."

Comment: that worked, I had expected it to use reflection an use the setter or getter method and not the property directly.

Comment: @boyd4715: You could try to move your annotations on the getters to see what happens when using property access (vs field access). On the other hand, the javadoc of `mappedBy` says *The field that owns the relationship* so I'm not sure this will change anything.

Comment: I was using mappedBy when the actual requirement was joincolumn lol

Answer (score 20):

I know the answer by [@Pascal Thivent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70604/pascal-thivent) has solved the issue. I would like to add a bit more to his answer to others who might be surfing this thread.

If you are like me in the initial days of learning and wrapping your head around the concept of using the `@OneToMany` annotation with the '`mappedBy`' property, it also means that the other side holding the `@ManyToOne` annotation with the `@JoinColumn` is the 'owner' of this bi-directional relationship.

Also, `mappedBy` takes in the *instance name* (`mCustomer` in this example) of the Class variable as an input and not the *Class-Type* (ex:Customer) or the entity name(Ex:customer).

BONUS : 
Also, look into the `orphanRemoval` property of `@OneToMany` annotation. If it is set to true, then if a parent is deleted in a bi-directional relationship, Hibernate automatically deletes it's children.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    Long userId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "sender", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Notification> sender;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "receiver", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Notification> receiver;
}

public class Notification implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id

    @Column(name = "NOTIFICATION_ID")
    Long notificationId;

    @Column(name = "TEXT")
    String text;

    @Column(name = "ALERT_STATUS")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    AlertStatus alertStatus = AlertStatus.NEW;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SENDER_ID")
    @JsonIgnore
    User sender;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "RECEIVER_ID")
    @JsonIgnore
    User receiver;
}
```

What I understood from the answer. mappedy="sender" value should be the same in the notification model. I will give you an example..

User model:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "**sender**", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Notification> sender;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "**receiver**", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Notification> receiver;
```

Notification model:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "sender", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Notification> **sender**;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "receiver", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Notification> **receiver**;
```

I gave bold font to user model and notification field. User model mappedBy="**sender** " should be equal to notification List  **sender**; and mappedBy="**receiver**" should be equal to notification List  **receiver**; If not, you will get error.